# Create Server Template discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Does anyone know how to make your discord bot create a server template of the guild the message was sent in?
I don't know how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried for now? Can you share your code or can you describe what was your steps so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this information documented on discord.js' docs. Here's an example:

```
message.guild.createTemplate("template name", "optional template description");
```

Of course, this will only work if your bot has "Manage Server" (or "Administrator") perms.

Relevant resources:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=createTemplate