# Apply server template discord.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

Is there a way to let the bot use a template? I know there is a way to create a template [Create Server Template discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65208215/create-server-template-discord-js) or by doing it by hand. But is there a way to apply a template with a bot? just like this:

`message.guild.applyTemplate('TemplateUrl')`

`message.guild.useTemplate('TemplateUrl')`

Answer (score 2):

**Edit [Discord.js v13](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js)**

Yes, it's possible now with [`<GuildTemplate>.sync()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildTemplate?scrollTo=sync).

> Syncs this template to the current state of the guild.
>
> Returns: Promise

**Initial Answer (Discord.js v12)**

Using Discord.js: *Not yet*.

Using the Discord API: *technically Yes*

As of now there is no way to apply a server template with a discord.js bot. However there is something interesting mentioned in the [Official Discord Devs Docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild-template).

> PUT `/guilds/{guild.id}/templates/{template.code}`
> Syncs the template to the guild's current state.
> Requires the MANAGE_GUILD permission.
> Returns the guild template object on success.

Source: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild-template#sync-guild-template

Also Discord.js v13 introduction mentions Guild Template API support in the [Update Notes/Changes in v13](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#guildtemplate).

> **GuildTemplate**
> Provides API support for server templates

I am going to adapt this answer once Discord.js v13 has been released.

Comment: Thank you @Behemoth but sadly will this not fix the problem I have. Hopefully Discord.js v14 will have a way to use the template that you just sync.